# how to write subquery using criteria

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa

please help me out writing criteria builder for this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM XYZ 
WHERE date_v < "2020/01" AND 
      id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM XYZ WHERE date_v = '2020/01')
```

i have looked at [using subqueries in jpa criteria api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163443/using-subqueries-in-jpa-criteria-api) but i am unable to figure it

I have tried using subquery and joins but it throwing different error after all i get to know that i need to get more clarity about query criteria usages. any help much appreciated

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create `XyzEntity` with `Long id` and `LocalDate date_v` fields.

```
// query
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<XyzEntity> query = cb.createQuery(XyzEntity.class);
Root<XyzEntity> root = query.from(XyzEntity.class);

LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2020, 1, 1);

// subquery
Subquery<Long> subQuery = query.subquery(Long.class);
Root<XyzEntity> subRoot = subQuery.from(XyzEntity.class);
Predicate idSubPredicate = cb.equal(root.get("id"), subRoot.get("id"));
Predicate dateSubPredicate = cb.equal(subRoot.get("date_v"), date);

subQuery.select(subRoot.get("id")).where(idSubPredicate, dateSubPredicate);

// query predicates
Predicate datePredicate = cb.greaterThan(root.get("date_v"), date);
Predicate notExistsPredicate = cb.exists(subQuery).not();

// query result
query.select(root).where(datePredicate, notExistsPredicate);

List<XyzEntity> result = entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```

Comment: it is executed without errors but resulted data not returning it returning null even data is there

Comment: @ alex valuiskyi any idea?

Comment: It is complicated to trace bugs without a single line of code. There are a lot of errors can lead to your problem https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: ya cool, i figured it out. the problem is when we searching NOT IN id in subquery. the id is not applying. like root.get("id").in(subQuery).not(). at cb.exists(subQuery).not();

Comment: The code was written without testing, so I missed `idSubPredicate` in the answer. Now should work

Answer (score 0):

I have mentioned the corrections in comments for the answer but I feel providing full solution seems good and helps others:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Entity> query = cb.createQuery(Entity.class);
Root<Entity> root = query.from(Entity.class);
// subquery
Subquery<Long> subQuery = query.subquery(Long.class);
Root<Entity> subRoot = subQuery.from(Entity.class);
Predicate subPredicate = cb.equal(subRoot.get("date_v"), dateValue);

subQuery.select(subRoot.get("id")).where(subPredicate);

// query predicates
Predicate datePredicate = cb.lessThan(root.get("date_v"), dateValue);
Predicate notExistsPredicate = root.get("id").in(subQuery).not();

// query result
query.select(root).where(datePredicate, notExistsPredicate);
Query d = entityManager.createQuery(query);
List<Entity> resultList = d.getResultList()
```